# Progress of mongodump operation jams at a random point

Tags: backup, mongodb, dump

We are executing remote mongodumps to backup collections. For some time now sporadically one of these dumps stops to progress any further and remains to log out the same amount of documents processed over and over:

```
2016-06-27T06:35:06.428+0000    [##############.......]  col  1140198/1853120  (61.5%)
2016-06-27T06:35:09.428+0000    [##############.......]  col  1140198/1853120  (61.5%)
2016-06-27T06:35:12.428+0000    [##############.......]  col  1140198/1853120  (61.5%)
```

This time the dump is stuck at this point for about four hours and more than 5000 log lines showing 61.5% of progress.

I can still access the MongoDB Server from the backup machine, mongodb answers to queries, no annomalies in the logs.

MongoDB version 2.6.12

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some other folks had this issue ([here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1152) or [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1381)) without any clear resolution. Someone [suggests](https://github.com/backup/backup/issues/699) adding `--quiet` to the `mongodump` command.

But maybe `mongodump` is not the correct way of doing it. From the documentation:

> **mongodump** and **mongorestore** are simple and efficient tools for backing
>   up and restoring small MongoDB deployments, but are not ideal for
>   capturing backups of larger systems

Also:

> When connected to a MongoDB instance, **mongodump** can adversely affect
>   mongod performance. If your data is larger than system memory, the
>   queries will push the working set out of memory, causing page faults

Some other methods of creating backups are detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-by-copying-underlying-data-files). Maybe „Filesystem Snapshots” or „cp or rsync” are more suitable to your use case.